# How to delete specific event entries from Event Log?

Tags: .net, windows-server-2008, event-log

My requirement is to read event entries from event log and store them in database. After reading single entry and storing into database, I need to remove this from event log.

I am using `EventLog` class to read event entries on same computer. This class is supporting to read entries one by one in loop but it's not allowing to delete entries one by one.

`EventLog` class supports to clear all entries in one shot only. I can't clear the full event log because new events are being added while read operation is going on.

Please let me know if I can use a different .Net class to achieve this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Manage windows events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563185/c-sharp-manage-windows-events)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible.. It's all or nothing. See this question:

[C# Manage windows events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563185/c-sharp-manage-windows-events)

Comment: the answers are quite old. framework changes may provide new features.