# How to delete event log source with EventRecordID using c#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, event-log, .net-5

I have tried with the following code to delete event log source. Referred with the document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventlog.delete?view=net-5.0

```
                    string applicationlog = "Application";
                    string mymachine = System.Environment.MachineName; 
                    EventLog myapplicationLog = new EventLog(applicationlog,
                       mymachine);
                    EventLogEntryCollection entries =
                       myapplicationLog.Entries;
                    int LogCount = entries.Count;
                    if (LogCount <= 0)
                    {
                        _logger.LogInformation("No Event Logs in the Log :");
                    }
                    if (EventLog.SourceExists("test123"))
                    {
                        // Find the log associated with this source.
                         logName = EventLog.LogNameFromSourceName("test123", mymachine);
                        // Make sure the source is in the log we believe it to be in.
                        if (logName != "Application")
                            return;
                        // Delete the source and the log.
                        EventLog.DeleteEventSource("test123", mymachine);
                        EventLog.Delete(logName, mymachine);                       
                        _logger.LogInformation(logName + " deleted.");
                    }
```

When i executing the above code, all events deleted. i need to delete specifically. How to delete event log with specific id(EventRecordID)?

Comment: You are deleting the whole log, because the statements you use doing that according to the docs you referred. If you want to delete just log entries: it is not possible at all, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17344067/how-to-delete-specific-event-entries-from-event-log

Comment: Can i delete event log source with specific id using powershell? is it possible usiing powershell?

Comment: @cly , this is & plus years old answer. this is possible now?

Comment: No. You can only clear the whole log. You cannot delete just one entry.