# How to delete event log using c#.net core with specific time interval

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-core, event-log

I have tried with the following code to get event log with specified time intervals.

```
EventLog log = new EventLog(application);
var Entries = log.Entries
     .Cast<EventLogEntry>()
     .Where(x => x.Source == sourceName && (x.TimeGenerated <= DateTime.Now && x.TimeGenerated >= calculatedLogTime))
     .Select(x => new
     {
         x.MachineName,
         x.Site,
         x.Source,
         x.Message,
         x.TimeGenerated,
         x.TimeWritten
     }).ToList();
```

From the above code, gets event log with specified time interval. then i have tried with clear that specified log using the code `Entries.Clear();`but log not cleared. I have cross checked windows event viewer. it doesn't cleared from event viewer. how to clear event log with the above code?

Comment: Add x to the Select method to put the actual long entry into the results.  Then you can delete the item.  You are only making a list of the items so clearing is just removing items from the list and not removing the object.

Comment: `Entries.Clear()` will only clear the list object that contains your anonymous `new { x.MachineName, x.Site, ... }` objects. To clear the system log, try this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventlog.delete?view=net-5.0#System_Diagnostics_EventLog_Delete_System_String_

Comment: `Entries.Clear()` only clears the List variable, not the actual EventLog. I do not believe it is possible to delete individual items from an Event Log. You can clear the entire Event Log using `log.Clear()`

Comment: @PeterB That will delete the log all together, not just clear the entries.

Comment: @RyanThomas I have tried with log.clear(); but it cleared entire log. i need to clear specific log.

Comment: By design windows event logs cannot be individually deleted (it is for security reasons)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the entries are not deleting is because you are calling the `Clear` method on the variable which is a list, so it is clearing this list, not the actual EventLog.

Windows does not allow you to delete individual entries from a log by design. See [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/8339/how-can-i-remove-specific-events-from-the-event-log-in-windows-server-2008#:%7E:text=There%20is%20no%20supported%20way,them%20appropriately%20within%20the%20application.) post on ServerFault for more info.

You can clear the log entirely using

```
log.Clear();
```

Or if you want to delete the log you can use

```
EventLog.Delete(application);
```

But I do not believe it is possible to remove specific entries using .NET alone.

There are also several other similar questions which have discussed this. This link shows a method of cloning the EventLog, clearing it and rewriting it without the entries you want to remove, which I believe is the only way to achieve what you want.

[C# Manage Windows Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563185/c-sharp-manage-windows-events)